# Configuring "build.gradle" for Kotlin module in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I'm developing an app and I want to separate the Android specific logic from the business logic ( "immutable" logic and Android independent), so I created two modules:

- **app** : Android specific code
- **domain** : Business logic ( written in Kotlin )

I'm using this **build.gradle** file for the kotlin module

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

    /* Annotations library */
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1'

    /* Dagger 2 library */
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.1'

   /* EventBus library */
   compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'

   /* JODA TIME - time and date library */
   compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.2'

  /*Rx Kotlin*/
  compile 'io.reactivex:rxkotlin:0.55.0'

  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.0.47-beta'
}

buildscript {

    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.1-2'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {

        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven{ url "http://repository.jetbrains.com/all" }
}
```

Is this the correct way to configure the kotlin module?

**PLUS:** I'm getting a **Gradle DSL method not found: 'provided()'** error. How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle doesn't have `provided` configuration by default. Instead it has `compileOnly`. So if you really want a dependency to be available only during compilation do the following:

```
compileOnly 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
```